# RGiesecke.DllExport not woking (exporting)

Tags: c#, dll, export, jna, dllexport

I'm trying to export C# functions to Java JNA.
Followed some tutorial but cant get it to export.

```
public class Class1
{
    [DllExport("add")]
    static int somar(int i)
    {
        return 1+i;
    }
}
```

I'm using:

- Created Class Library project;
- The Release/x64 Platform Target;
- DLL Export Viewer to check exported functions;

The build process don't show any intervention of RGiesecke.DllExport.
And the output is only .dll and .pdb files.

Can someone tell what is missing?